# Differentiate $f(x) =(a+x) ^x$

Tags: calculus

I want to differentiate $f(x) =(a+x) ^x$, where $a>0$ is fixed. I thought about writing this as a composition of functions, but I can't find them.

Comment: you can write $f(x) = F \circ g(x)$ where $F(x,y) = (a+x)^y$ and $g(x) = (x,x)$, and conclude with multivariate chain rule

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: Write this as the form $$f\left( x \right)={ e }^{ x\ln { \left( x+a \right)  }  }$$
then differentiate

Answer (score 1):

We write $(a+x)^x=e^{x\ln(a+x)}$, whereby the derivative is easy to get:
$$(e^{x\ln(a+x)})'=e^{x\ln(a+x)}(\ln(a+x)+x/(a+x))=(a+x)^x(\ln(a+x)+x/(a+x))$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to take logarithms so $$\ln f(x)=x\ln (a+x)$$

Then if you differentiate the left hand side with respect to $x$ you get $$\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac {f'(x)}{(a+x)^x}$$and you can differentiate the right-hand side too.

This taking logarithms first is sometimes a handy practical technique for simplifying the workings when differentiating complicated expressions.